# Selector for finding the first select list with a specific value

Tags: jquery, class, select, selector

I have several selects on a page with the same class `VirtueClass`. Now I want to change the selected item on the first select on the page where the value equals `0`, e.g. the first "free" select on the page.

How can I write such a selector?

Comment: I think you should provide a working copy on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver While jsfiddle is good to showcase a problem, a question should stand on its own, so also post code example here. Furthermore, the question should only contain the question itself, not some meta about which question it is nor a signum.

Comment: @k0pernikus:ya your right about that.theoritical  things are always tough to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.VirtueClass').filter(function(){
    return this.value == 0;
 }).eq(0);
```

This will select the first item that is set to zero

Comment: Ok, so how do I change the selected item for this select now once i have it?

Comment: @Aztaroth You are asking a new followup question. Comments are not meant for that purpose. You may search for similar questions and see if your question is answered there, or ask a new one linking to this question.

Comment: It's not the value of the select itself that should be 0, like I think this example says? But rather the value of the selects selected option